# Convert generic csv to xml in Go

Tags: xml, csv, go

I am trying to convert generic csv files into xml files. The csv file has a header line. The header values represent the element name, and the values in the respective column are the corresponding element values.

My approach so far:

```
// Read the csv file
file, err := os.Open(*i)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Error opening input file: %v\n", err)
}
defer file.Close()

r := csv.NewReader(file)
r.Comma, _ = utf8.DecodeRuneInString(*s)
lines, err := r.ReadAll()

// header values
header := lines[0]
// Write the xml file
fileOut, err := os.Create(*o)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("Error opening input file: %v\n", err)
}
defer fileOut.Close()

for _, l := range lines {
  for i, elem := range l {
    // TODO: Something here is missing...
    xml.EscapeText(fileOut, []byte(header[i]))

    xml.EscapeText(fileOut, []byte(elem))

  }
```

**Question**: How do I make it the last part in xml write section work? Or is there a more efficient way of converting csv files into xml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are two solutions:
 You can reflect the data into a struct,only when you can get the struct , fields and tags.  then output XML by methods from xml package.
 But,if you don't know the struct as I face.there is a stupid but easy way,writing as string, as blow:

```
data := XML_HEADER
data = data + "<records>\n"
for i := 2; i < len(records); i++ {
 data = data + "  <record "
  for j := 0; j < len(records[i]); j++  {
   data = data + head[j] + `="` + records[i][j] + `" `
                                        }
 data = data + "/>\n"              }
 data = data + "</records>"
 ioutil.WriteFile(xmlFileName, []byte(data), 0644)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go has built in support for reading and writing CSV and XML.

Checkout the following packages:

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/

It should be no problem to read your CSV data into a struct and then output XML to a file

Comment: The question is for a **generic** CSV - i.e. not a struct with named XML fields.